# git push doesn't work on one repository with permission denied

Tags: git

I created a new repository.  It seemed like I got an error when I tried to push my first commit - I think it said something like `public key mismatch, are you sure...`.  I chose 'yes'.

Now when I try to push I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried removing .git and redoing steps to initialize git

Push works on another repository

Can you give me some pointers on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Are you sure you are communicating with the correct server?

Comment: The remote repo is not authorizing you to push. If it uses key-based auth, make sure your key is added to the remote, and you are using the `ssh:` protocol to push (not `https`)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [these steps](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey) and it will be done.